# Detect if a user has denied any permission in my Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am asking for a few extra permissions using the `scope` parameter when launching the facebook application. Is there any way I can know immediately which permissions have been denied by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ for more information on the user object's permissions connection.

Comment: These links could have been provided as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple function (modified from a class I wrote to simplify Facebook API calls) to check if there are discrepencies between the 'scope' of the Facebook app and the permissions granted by the user.

```
function checkPermissions($scope, $facebook)
{
    // Break the scope into an array
    $scope = array_map('trim', explode(",", $scope));

    // Get the users permissions from Facebook and put them in an array
    $getUserPerms = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
    $userPerms = array_keys($getUserPerms['data'][0]);

    // Permissions not granted is the difference between these arrys
    $ungrantedPerms = array_diff($scope, $userPerms);

    if ( ! empty($ungrantedPerms)) {
        // authenticate user again
    }
}
```

Is assumes the scope is formatted in the following way:

```
$scope = 'email, user_about_me, user_likes, manage_pages, publish_stream';
```

Comment: Awesome. I know it's late (really late) but I figured it would help someone else, especially considering how hard it is to find this type of information in the Facebook API documentation!